# Configure merge_block_size in sphinx search engine

Tags: indexing, sphinx

I am powering a web search using Sphinx, and am getting the following error message while building the indexes:

> WARNING: sort_hits: merge_block_size=76 kb too low, increasing mem_limit may improve performance

The problem is I can't find any documentation on where this setting is configured. I'm somewhat versed on Sphinx setup, so I just need to know where the setting is configured.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably happening because you're trying to index too many items at once.  Make sure you're using [ranged queries](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-range).  If you're already using ranged queries, increasing the `mem_limit`, as it suggests, may help.  The `merge_block_size` is based on `mem_limit` and the number of documents.

If you're curious as to how it generates that number, check out the source.  It's freely available.

Answer (score 3):

> In sphinx.conf:
>
> ```
> sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM documents
> sql_range_step = 1000
> sql_query = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end
> ```
>
> If the table contains document IDs from 1 to, say, 2345, then
>   sql_query would be run three times:
>
> 1. with $start replaced with 1 and $end replaced with 1000;
> 2. with $start replaced with 1001 and $end replaced with 2000;
> 3. with $start replaced with 2000 and $end replaced with 2345.
>
> Obviously, that's not much of a difference for 2000-row table, but
>   when it comes to indexing 10-million-row MyISAM table, ranged queries
>   might be of some help.
>
> http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ranged-queries

Hope it works for you.